# Option CSS Not Working - user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

I've been searching for a few days for an answer to this. **The option element is not getting styled.** Currently, I'm not sure if it's this user agent stylesheet overriding my style for the **option** element. I tried styling the option in my own CSS file however it gets canceled out. Every other HTML element on the same page is working and is styled correctly. It's just the  element. I'm also using bootstrap.

What I've tried to solve:

1. add classes
2. add id
3. add !important
4. inline styling

Basically everything to target a specific/all option element(s) but it all does not seem to work. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Or is there something I'm missing which I can't seem to see? Thank you for your suggestions.

```
select#cur_to option{
  background-color: white !important;
  color: black !important;  
}
```

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">  
     <select class="select-drop form-control" style="font-size:25px; height:56px;" id="cur_to" name="currency_to">     
        <?php
          for ($row = 0; $row < count($data); $row++) {
            echo "<option>".$data[$row]["currency_code"]."</option>";         
          }
        ?>    
      </select>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include a code snippet and explain exactly what is "not working"

Comment: Is your css enqueued? If it is you can include a `dependency`... this may overcome it not being a priority... refer: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Comment: As @Andres has written in his answer, there are only a couple of things you can do to style `<option>` tag. More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208814/2800461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling option tags it's almost impossible, you can only style a few things.

Since you have bootstrap installed, you can add this plugin for this purpose: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect